# TimeDistributed Layers vs. ConvLSTM-2D

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, lstm

Could anyone explains for me the differences between Time-Distributed Layers (from [Keras Wrapper](https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/)) and ConvLSTM-2D ([Convolutional LSTM](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.04214v1.pdf)), for purposes, usage, etc.?

Answer (score 5):

Both applies to a sequence of data.

Time Distributed is a very straightforward layer wrapper which only applies a layer (usually dense layer) on each time point. You need it when you need to change the shape of output tensor, especially the dimension of features, instead of sample size and time step.

ConvLSTM2D, is much more complex. You need to understand cnn and rnn layer first, where LSTM is one of most popular rnn. LSTM itself is applied on a sequence of of tensor, which is used for NLP, time series and for each time step the input is 1-dimension. cnn, the conv part, is usually used to learn from image, which is 2-dimension but don't have a sequence (time step). Combined together, convLSTM is used to learn image in a sequence, like video.